# disable an input field if the other is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How to get this done supposing if a user clicks the below field and selects a file

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
```

then the

```
<input type="text" name="ytube" id="ytube" value="" />
```

gets disabled and if you tube is clicked with  then the image option gets disabled?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you attempted anything ?

Comment: `image option gets disabled` - does this means a file input field?

Comment: yes i tried but not able to, image option yes i refered to file field, which ever has value to it the other should get disavled is what im trying to get

Comment: i tried this $(function(){
    $('#disimg').on('keyup',function(){   
     if($(this).val()!=="") {
        $('#disytube').prop('disabled', true);
      } else {
       $('#disytube').attr('disabled', false);
      }
 });
$('#disytube').on('keyup',function(){ 
   if($(this).val()!=="") {
    $('#disimg').prop('disabled', true);
     } else {
       $('#disimg').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});  
}); 

but only file field gets disabled but ytube still stays active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery

```
  $(function() {
     $("input:file").change(function (){
       $("#ytube").prop('disabled', true);
     });
     $("#ytube").change(function (){
       if($("#ytube").val().trim() != ""){
          $("#file").prop('disabled', true);
       }else{
          $("#file").prop('disabled', false);
       }

     });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m3hu2ruc/4/

Comment: its working but only for ytube but is i enter value to it the file option not getting disabled?

Comment: works like a charm but which version of jquery should i use here? i have jquery.min on my script but its not working locally

Comment: I have https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js with the jsfiddle

Comment: facing an issue if i remove text from ytube field file is still disabled?

Comment: @Seeker change inside youtube change function _if($("#ytube").val().trim() != ""){
          $("#file").prop('disabled', true);
       }else{
          $("#file").prop('disabled', false);
       }_

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#file"]').change(function(){
        $('#ytube').attr('disabled','disabled');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable textbox only if file is selected then use this code

**CODE**

```
$('input:file').change(function(){
   if($(this).val()!=''){
     $('input:text').prop('disabled','disabled');
   }
})
```

And to disable input file on textbox click

**CODE**

```
$('input:text').on('click', function(){
  $('input:file').prop('disabled','disabled');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
$("#file").change(function() {
  $("#ytube").attr("disabled","disabled");
});

$("#ytube").change(function() {
  if($("#ytube").val().trim() != ""){
    $("#file").attr("disabled","disabled");
  }else{
    $("#file").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

If you want remove text from text inputbox, file input will again enable. But I suggest to keep a button to reset.

Comment: thanks you all so much for your precious time its sorted :)

Comment: which version of jquery should i use? locally its not working with jquery.min

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>